# Alter stored procedure if condition is met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am looking to alter a stored procedure if a condition exists.  I want to leave the stored procedure as is if the condition is not met, so drop/create is not really an option.

Trying to put the contents of ALTER PROC inside an IF block is throwing up errors for me.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you trying to alter a stored procedure programmatically?  Is there some way you could make the stored procedure data-driven somehow and alter the data that drives the stored proc instead?

Comment: An update need to be made to the sproc to add additional functionality.  The SQL DB used was using merge replicated.  Because the sproc is a replicated article drop/create is not an option.  ALTER is allowed and the changes would replicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
IF (condition)
  EXEC ('ALTER PROC ...')
```

ALTER/CREATE PROC must be first in the batch so this is the only way. Unless you do this

```
IF NOT (condition)
   RAISERROR('abort connection with high severity', 20, 1)
GO
ALTER PROC ...

GO
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the NOEXEC setting to do it, but be careful. Once you turn NOEXEC ON, you must turn it back to OFF at the end of your script.

```
IF (CONDITION)
    SET NOEXEC OFF --Enables execution of code (Default)
ELSE 
    SET NOEXEC ON --Disables execution of code
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE MYPROC
AS
--STATEMENTS
GO --END OF ALTER BLOCK
SET NOEXEC OFF --RESTORES NOEXEC SETTING TO ITS DEFAULT
```